# Interfacing pygame with dispmanx - performance

Tags: performance, gpu, pygame

I'm working on a graphical application, made for console mode, and facing some performance issues when working with large resolution (1920px wide here).

One part of the display, a video background, is generated and displayed via pygame (SDL 1.2 python bindings).
The other part of the display, the UI, is also generated with pygame, but is displayed as a GPU overlay (based on the dispmanx API : https://github.com/AndrewFromMelbourne/raspidmx), via a fork of pngview, launched as a subprocess.

Here is the detailled steps and timings :
 - UI image is generated on a pygame Surface. (take 0.03s)
 - Pygame surface is converted to a (x,y,4) int8 array, representing the RGBA array. (also take 0.03s)
`layerRGBA = np.fromstring(layerUI.get_buffer().raw,np.uint8).reshape(resX,resY, 4)`
 - The pixel array is then written to a memory mapped file (take 0.03s too)
`fp = np.memmap("/tmp/layerRGBA.raw",dtype='int8', mode='w+', shape=(resX,resY,4))
fp[:] =  res`
 - Then the subprocess is told to refresh the UI via a stdin message. (take 0.00s)

Can I expect to achieve better performance on the conversion or mmap part ?
Or is there a faster way to communicate this RGBA layer from my main python app to my dispmanx C program than mmap?

Thank you for your suggestions !

Comment: top I'm actually trying to do the same thing where I want to overlay some images over my omxplayer video in python. Can you share your code or experience with me? I'm rather new to Linux and Python. Thank you!

Comment: The easiest solution would be to launch multiple `pngview` session on different layers. See https://github.com/AndrewFromMelbourne/raspi2png

Comment: oops, read `raspi2png` instead of `pngview` ^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it : mmal is slightly faster than mmap.

Refer to the picamera module, overlay section, for a real-world implementation.